# Linear regression with over 15 million datapoints with several factors

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, large-data

I want to use linear regression on a very large dataset with costs corresponding to about 15 million entries. For each of the 15 million entries I have several independent categorical variables.
I want to estimate the costs of each categorical factor variable. Furthermore, I have the constraint that I want to estimate all categories except for the first category to be "neutral". This means that if we sum all the costs corresponding to this categorical variable for all the people , the total sum will be 0 (this obviously means that there will be negative costs as well).

Are there any easy ways to do this?
Currently I have an implementation in Python in which I build a matrix of ones and zeros for each factor in each category to indicate whether or not it belongs to this category. When I have constructed this large matrix, I use a python solver in scipy to minimize the Mean Squared Error.
This takes very long and does not always converge (I tried different size tests).

Comment: Perhaps try (a) different software, (b) using an existing implementation which may be more efficient than rolling your own. If that fails you could try a programming site where people might be able to debug your code.

Comment: Call me stupid, but I do not understand the task at hand. What is a cost? Is cost the dependend variable or are costs the regression coefficients of some dummy variables and which sum exactly is supposed to be zero? What is a factor, what a category, why do you need a matrix for each factor in each category? What are different size tests?

Comment: (1) It's not clear what you mean by "sum all the costs... the total sum will be 0."  Could you elaborate? (2) I just generated a dataset conforming to your description, with "several" interpreted as 5 and with 15 million entries.  Using a single `lm` command in `R` it took 40 seconds to fit.  Does that count as "very long"?  (3) What do you mean by "converge", given that linear regression is accomplished by solving the Normal equations, to which "convergence" towards a solution doesn't apply?